# c++ cgi file streaming

Tags: c++, file-io, cgi

i've been trying to serve binary files (mp3 files as example) through cgi. The point is that i want to make files accessible only through an special script an not through the webserver itself. Till now i got:

```
int main() {
    cgiWriteEnvironment("/CHANGE/THIS/PATH/capcgi.dat");
    cgiHeaderContentType("audio/mpeg");

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("D:/something.mp3", "r");
    char buffer[4];

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fread(buffer, 4, 1, fp);
        printf("%x",buffer);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

It's putting out something to stdout and the browser is trying to open vlc (so the header should be correct...) but the players can't handle the data :-(

Comment: You need to write binary, not hex.  Use fwrite.  Or, since you're using C++, you could go the stream route.  Also, you should probably have a buffer larger than 4 chars.  Lower level buffering should take care of most of the penalty, but a 4 char buffer is tiny if you're pumping a huge file through (think an 8MB file would require 2m calls to fread).

Answer (score 1):

You're encoding the `.mp3` file in hexidecimal, a sequence of ASCII 0s and 4s and Cs and so forth.  You want `fwrite()`, which will preserve the original format of the bytes you're writing.  Also: a buffer size of 4 bytes will work, but I'd recommend 4k (4048) or 8k (8192) bytes instead.  On a modern machine it doesn't matter, but calls to `fread()` are (relatively) slow so you want to make as few as possible.

Also: this is a pretty strange thing to want.  What problem are you trying to solve, and why can't a normal web server solve it?